# MvvmCross Async command lock

Tags: asynchronous, xamarin, command, mvvmcross

I have alot of button in my application. They are placed next to each other. All of the methods are IMvxAsyncCommand type. I figured out some missmatches after tests done by users. I have found duplicate operations - two diffrent buttons are called in almost same time.

What did I do is created my own SafeAsyncCommand class and inheret from MvxAsyncCommand. My goal is to create delay between executes - I want to prevent double click in given delay in below case 0.5s.

There is my work:

```
public static class SafeCommandSettings
    {
        public static bool CanExecute { get; private set; }
        public static TimeSpan Delay => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);

        static SafeCommandSettings()
        {
            CanExecute = true;
        }

        public static async void Pause()
        {
            if (!CanExecute) return;

            CanExecute = false;
            await Task.Delay(Delay);
            CanExecute = true;
        }
    }

    public class SafeAsyncCommand : MvxAsyncCommand
    {
        public SafeAsyncCommand(Func<Task> execute, Func<bool> canExecute = null, bool allowConcurrentExecutions = false)
            : base(execute, canExecute, allowConcurrentExecutions)
        {
        }

        public SafeAsyncCommand(Func<CancellationToken, Task> execute, Func<bool> canExecute = null, bool allowConcurrentExecutions = false)
            : base(execute, canExecute, allowConcurrentExecutions)
        {
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsyncImpl(object parameter)
        {
            if (!SafeCommandSettings.CanExecute) return;

            SafeCommandSettings.Pause();
            await base.ExecuteAsyncImpl(parameter);
        }
    }

    public class SafeAsyncCommand<T> : MvxAsyncCommand<T>
    {
        public SafeAsyncCommand(Func<T, Task> execute, Func<T, bool> canExecute = null, bool allowConcurrentExecutions = false)
            : base(execute, canExecute, allowConcurrentExecutions)
        {
        }

        public SafeAsyncCommand(Func<T, CancellationToken, Task> execute, Func<T, bool> canExecute = null, bool allowConcurrentExecutions = false)
            : base(execute, canExecute, allowConcurrentExecutions)
        {
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsyncImpl(object parameter)
        {
            if (!SafeCommandSettings.CanExecute) return;

            SafeCommandSettings.Pause();
            await base.ExecuteAsyncImpl(parameter);
        }
    }
```

I thought this is working but I saw users were able to do it again. Do I miss some knowledge about async methods or static thread safe?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of delaying things, consider using `AsyncLock` by Stephen Cleary or lookup `Interlocked.CompareExchange`.

As far as I can tell from here, you shouldn't use a static `CanExecute` in your case, as it locks all commands using your "safe" command at once.
And there is the possibility of race conditions, since you aren't changing the value of `CanExecute` locked.

Answer (score 3):

In order to do so you can take advantage of [MvxNotifyTask](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/mvxnotifytask) that is a wrapper of the `Task` that watches for different task states and you'll run on your command and do something like this (notice that you don't need the command to be `MvxAsyncCommand`):

```
public MvxNotifyTask MyNotifyTaskWrapper { get; private set; }

public MvxCommand MyCommand { get; private set; }

private void InitializeCommands()
{
    // this command is executed only if the task has not started (its wrapper is null) or the task is not in progress (its wrapper is not IsNotCompleted)
    this.MyCommand = new MvxCommand(() => this.MyNotifyTaskWrapper = MvxNotifyTask.Create(() => this.MyLogicAsync()),
                                    () => this.MyNotifyTaskWrapper == null || !this.MyNotifyTaskWrapper.IsNotCompleted);
}

private async Task MyLogicAsync()
{
    // my async logic
}
```

So as soon the async process is started the command can't be executed again preventing duplicate operations, and you can start it again when that task completes.

If you have to disable multiple commands execution when running some task just add the same `CanExecute` condition on the different commands or mix conditions of different `MvxNotifyTask`

Also check that the `MvxNotifyTask` raises property-changed notifications that you can subscribe to or bind to in your view displaying a "loading" or something like that when performing the operation.

*Note: if you are using Mvx < 5.5 you won't have `MvxNotifyTask` but you can use [NotifyTaskCompletion](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/NotifyTaskCompletion) done by Stephen Cleary that is almost the same as `MvxNotifyTask` and it is from where `MvxNotifyTask` was based on.*

HIH

Comment: Thanks for great answer :)

Comment: I coded this answer and the buttons would keep on taking user input if pressed very fast. I have read on the docs that MvvmCross does not support CanExecute for commands very well. What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: on `MyLogicAsync`, put a `await Task.Yield();` as a first line and let me know if that helps solving your issue